# Horseshoe distribution

Tags: distributions, simulation, dimensionality-reduction, nonlinear

Studying nonlinear dimension reduction topics I came across a "horseshoe distribution" or "horsheshoe phenomena". Figure (b) [[source](http://perso.uclouvain.be/michel.verleysen/seminars/PCA%20UPV%20BW%202spp.pdf), p. 12] depicting horseshoe distribution is included below.

[image: Horseshoe distribution.]

I do not have a good idea how to simulate this type of distribution.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply formulate a parabolic function fo each fixed value in a particular dimension (say for the z axis) and add a random noise component to it.